# Why are functions run in the module script file not in the window object?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, javascript-objects

The script file embedded directly in the HTML file, the functions contained in the `window` object. We can check with the following code.

```
    for(let i in window)
    {
        if ((typeof window[i]).toString() === "function" && !window[i].toString().includes("[native code]"))
        {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(window[i]);
            console.log("\n\n");
        }
    }
```

[image]

But when I run a function indirectly by importing it from `module` why isn't it in there?
This is my file structure.

```
 1. index.html
 2. script.js
 3. moduleScript.js
 4. ModuleScript
    - moduleScript01.js
    - moduleScript02.js
```

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Event Listener</title>
    <script src="moduleScript.js" type="module"></script>s
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" defer>
        import * as moduleScript from "./moduleScript.js";
        
        console.log(moduleScript.moduleScript01.Level01(1,2));
        console.log(moduleScript.moduleScript02.Level02(1,2, 3));
        console.log("\n\n");
        
        for(let i in window)
        {
            if ((typeof window[i]).toString() === "function" && !window[i].toString().includes("[native code]"))
            {
                console.log(i);
                console.log(window[i]);
                console.log("\n\n");
            }
        }
        
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function Level01 (a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}

function Level02 (a, b, c)
{
    return Level01(a,b) - c;
}

function Level03 (a, b)
{
    return  Level02(a,b, 1) * 5;
}

function print ()
{
    console.log("Hello world");
}
```

moduleScript.js

```
export * as moduleScript01 from "./ModuleScript/moduleScript01.js";
export * as moduleScript02 from "./ModuleScript/moduleScript02.js";
```

moduleScript01.js

```
function Level01 (a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}

export
{
    Level01
}
```

moduleScript02

```
function Level02 (a, b, c)
{
    return Level01(a,b) - c;
}

export
{
    Level02
}
```

Comment: That's a deliberate feature of modules. Over-using the global name space is bad programming practice.

Comment: @Pointy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules I don't see them mentioning purpose in this. Functions when executed will "go to" or "register" with the window object, correct?

Comment: Only when the code is running in global scope. Code for modules is executed in module scope.